# How can I perform a math expression using a string the script receives via command line?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this small program that uses AHK as its back end engine. In this program, I would like to implement a "variables" feature to perform very basic math operations (addition/multiplication etc).

the variables/objects being referenced are predefined in the AHK script being called via command line:

`.\Shift_IN.Ahk "$Start-5"`

`.\Shift_OUT.Ahk "$End+5"`

A condensed example of a script I would call is:

```
; A_args[1] := "$Start-5"                        ;An example of an incoming string
Input   := StrReplace(Parameters[1],"$",,null)   ;Remove the "$" symbol, last parameters seems to be mandatory, I gave it null 

Start   := 25                                    ;<---- minus 5 this variable
Current := 7   
End     := 50  

NewStartFrameIs := % %input%                     ;<---- I am assuming  that I placed "start-5" here         
MsgBox, % "NewStartFrameIs: " NewStartFrameIs    ;NewStartFrameIs's value should be 20
```

The script does not run though, I get errors, the most common being:

```
 ERROR :--->   NewStartFrameIs := % %input% ... contains an illegal character:
```

when I tried this `NewStartFrameIs := %input%` I also got the same error
How can I get AHK to think the `% %input%` is an expression I want it to perform and not a string?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets have special meaning in AHK for defining [Objects](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Objects.htm).
And
variable names in an [expression](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#Expressions) are not enclosed in percent signs. Literal strings must be enclosed in double quotes to distinguish them from variables:

```
Start   := 25 
Current := 7   
End     := 50 

Parameters := ["$"Start-5, "$"End+5]  ; defines an array; literal strings must be enclosed in double quotes
MsgBox, % Parameters[1]
Input   := StrReplace(Parameters[1],"$",,null)
NewStartFrameIs := input  ; variable names in an expression are not enclosed in percent signs      
MsgBox, % "NewStartFrameIs: " NewStartFrameIs ; NewStartFrameIs's value should be 20
```

Comment: You dont realise how man questions this answered for me, thank you